# Where is a good place to learn data structures?

Tags: data-structures

I am interested in learning data structures. Where should I learn them?

I have looked around Coursera but not sure if I will understand them.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Data-Structures-Algorithms-Made-Easy/dp/1468108867

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to master data structures is practice. Just take problems,

- Step 1. try it on your own
- Step 2. if you are unable to get it, see the solution
- Step 3. try to write code to it.
- Step 4. If you still face problems, see the code,trace it. Write on
  your own.

References to Data Structures and Algorithms Problems:

```
1.<http://geeksforgeeks.org>
2.<http://leetcode.com>
3.<https://codechef.com>
```

Comment: That's like saying: Don't use cars, reinvent the wheel the cog and the engine from scratch. No, you should read and learn, use existing resources to learn about data stuctures (and anything else) - and then for deep learning use them and implement them. Do you really advise for anyone who wants to learn data structures to reinvent on himself things like hash functions and self balancing trees?

Comment: I don't mean to start from trees,linked lists, I mean to start from basic arrays itself, but knowing theoretically is different from practice, I suggested him/her to start practicing, then you will automatically know theory...

Comment: No, he won't. Don't get me wrong - I don't think practice is not a good thing, but `Don't follow any video lectures, don't read anything.` is the worst advise I have ever seen given to someone who asks how to master something.

Comment: Okay sorry, I didn't noticed it... Yes, it's worst advise... edited my answer...  I assumed that he know atleast basics and advised....

Comment: Following this suggestion is the equivalent of learning to write by headbutting the keyboard.

Comment: what's wrong in that?? by the way, why are you insulting me saying 'Headbutting the Keyboard' ,

Answer (score 0):

I am also interested in data structures. It is a good part of CS to learn after Python or Java or C++ (a recommendation of many).

A good place would be UDemy. It has great instructors and nice courses.